# How to use Angular directive in Salesforce

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

How to use angular directive in Salesforce
My directive html page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
  <td>
    <div class="address-container">
        <p data-once-text="addr.company"></p>
        <p><span class="once-addr" data-once-text="addr.city"></span>, <span class="once-addr" data-once-text="addr.state"></span></p>
        <p><a href="javascript:;" details="addr" shipment-details = ''>View</a> <span>|</span> <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="removeAddress(acc.id, addr.id)">Remove</a></p>
    </div>
</td>
</apex:page>
```

My directive call

```
mydirective.directive('shipmentAddress', ['CartService', function(CartService){
    return{
        scope: true,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'apex/shipment_addresses_tplhtml',
        controller: function($scope){
            this.addressInfo = $scope.addr;
            $scope.removeAddress = function(accountId, addrId){
                if(confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this shipping address?')){
                    CartService.deleteCartAddress(accountId, addrId).then(function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $scope.$emit('refreshCart');
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

in my index.html

```
 <tr class="addresses">
    <td shipment-address  ng-repeat="addr in acc.addresses" ng-if="addr.added == true"></td>
 </tr>
```

But I am getting error in SaleForce/VisualForce as **Attribute name "shipment-address" associated with an element type "td" must be followed by the ' = ' character.**

Comment: why can't you add the `=`  ?

Comment: If I add = so what will be value of that

Comment: angular won't care since you aren't using it in scope. Try empty string. I don't know anything about salesforce but am guessing it is a template engine problem and if that makes it happy the client side will be too

Answer (score 2):

Just do it like this:

```
<tr class="addresses">
  <td shipment-address="true" ng-repeat="addr in acc.addresses" ng-if="addr.added == true"></td>
</tr>
```

That should remove the error. Empty string did not work for me but some value there will do it.